# In Angular how can I pass two parameters into formControlName

Tags: angular, form-control

I want to pass two parameters to the `formControlName` to make multiple cases like shown in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsFoa.png)

Comment: if you have two validators, ask about `form.get('firstName).errors?.required` and `form.get('firstName).errors?.minLength` (is the same FormControl that can to have two differents errors)

Comment: Thanks a lot , this is a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

after showing your code this can't be possible, because you need two inputs for first and last name.

If you are taking both names in single input you can get in one control and separate using the javascript split feature.

Answer (score 0):

Both Eliseo and Harikrushna Patel give key information.
A formcontrol can only have one name, but there are different ways to impose validation. In the ts-template, here's a code-snippet with an example for a required field with a minimum required string length of 5 characters:

```
initializeForm() {
    this.personForm = this.form.group({
         firstName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
    })
}
```

In the html-template with ngClass, here's a code snippet with an example:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="articlecode"
                                   id="articlecode"
                                   [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && formGroup.controls.articlecode.errors }" readonly>
```

If you still need help, please post your formgroup-code + explicitly state the rules you want to impose for the input.